# React-select width issue when using semantic ui

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, semantic-ui, react-select

I am designing a simple form using Semantic UI and React-Select, but I am facing the issue of react-select-input field. The width of react-select not working as expected.

The complete code is on - https://codesandbox.io/s/lp59z8r8oq

Please suggest some solution.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following and it is working:

```
style={{minWidth:"2em"}}
```

for the following piece of the code:

```
<Form.Field width={3}><Select placeholder='Options' options={options} 
    style={{minWidth:"10em"}}/></Form.Field>
```